# Using @RolesAllowed in Spring Boot Application secured with keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I want to create a microservice using Spring Boot 2 and secure it with keycloak. I used the new `keycloak-spring-boot-2-starter:4.0.0.Beta3` dependency.

My KeycloakConfig:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class KeycloakConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keyCloakAuthProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keyCloakAuthProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());

    auth.authenticationProvider(keyCloakAuthProvider);
}

@Bean
public KeycloakConfigResolver KeyCloakConfigResolver() {
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
}

@Bean
@Override
protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
    //noinspection unchecked
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return registrationBean;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
    //noinspection unchecked
    FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
    return registrationBean;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().denyAll();

}
```

If i replaced my configure-method with following all works fine for my bearer-only-client:

```
super.configure(http);
    http
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/service/example/ping*").hasRole("user")
            .anyRequest().denyAll();
```

But what i want to do is to annotate my Webservices with `@RolesAllowed("myRole")` to controll access. All other services should be denied by default. If im trying to do, its not working. Does anyone has an idea why and how i could do so?

Greetings from Germany!

Comment: `its not working`: please, develop it. Do you get any exception?